# Matching a string in a filename

Tags: python, regex

I have lots of files as `mydir/somethingXXending.csv`. I want to access these file names together with what I used as a placeholder `XX`. At the moment I do

```
from glob import glob
from re import re

for file in glob.glob('.mydir/something**ending.csv'): # i know that one star suffices here
    re.split('ending', re.split('something', file)[1])[0] # gives me xx
```

Is there any less hassle-some way to achieve this?

Comment: you can use `file[len('something'):-len('ending.csv')]` since both `ending.csv` and `something` are known and constant

Comment: I' not sure, but your question let me think that `XX` is _always_ two-characters long. In that eventuality, `??` is probably better than `**`. Still in that case, `file[-len("ending.csv")-2:][0:2]` would do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are importing the `re` module, so why not using a regex. It will also improve readability:

```
import glob
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'something(.*?)ending')
for file in glob.glob('.mydir/something**ending.csv'):
    xx = pattern.search(file).group(1)
```